# Computing Sky View Factor in GrassGis

Tags: grass

Hy community,

I´m currently working on my Master Thesis and I have to compute the "sky view factor". Since ESRI Arcmap is not a helpful choice to do that, I found that it is fairly easy to compute with GrassGIS (V.7) using the r.skyview command.

But I get an error message in the logfile i can´t really deal with. Hope that someone of you is experienced with that kind of problem and can help me out with this.

Here is what the GrassGIS output says:

```
    *(Fri Jan 09 16:17:10 2015)                                                      
    r.skyview input=Subset@PERMANENT output=Subset_SVF ndir=16 maxdistance=15.0     
    Unknown module parameter "keyword" at line 21
    Unknown module parameter "keyword" at line 22
    FEHLER: Value <rast> ambiguous for parameter <type>
            Valid options: raster,raster_3d,vector,old_vector,ascii_vector,labels,region,group,all
    Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "C:\Users\Axel-HP\AppData\Roaming\GRASS7\addons/scripts/r.skyview.py", line 120, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
            File "C:\Users\Axel-HP\AppData\Roaming\GRASS7\addons/scripts/r.skyview.py", line82, in main
        old_maps = _get_horizon_maps()
            File "C:\Users\Axel-HP\AppData\Roaming\GRASS7\addons/scripts/r.skyview.py", line 114, in_get_horizon_maps
       pattern=TMP_NAME + "*")[gcore.gisenv()['MAPSET']]
            File "C:\Temp\GRASSGIS7\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 1176, in list_grouped
       type=types, pattern=pattern,
       exclude=exclude).splitlines():
            File "C:\Temp\GRASSGIS7\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 425, in read_command
       return handle_errors(returncode, stdout, args, kwargs)
            File "C:\Temp\GRASSGIS7\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 308, in handle_errors
       returncode=returncode)
       grass.exceptions.CalledModuleError: Module run None
            ['g.list', '--q', '-m', 'type=rast', 'pattern=tmp_horizon_2340*'] ended with error
       Process ended with non-zero return code 1. See errors in the (error) output.
       (Fri Jan 09 16:17:11 2015) Befehl ausgeführt (1 Sek)*
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tested r.skyview and it is working. There were big changes in GRASS module parameter names recently which caused the trouble, but now it should work without problems.